# express.js without affecting response

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

Let's say we have a controller which fetches data from 3rd party service, save that data to db and send response to the client:

```
const findUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.params.username) {
    const resp_ = await fetchFunction (req.params.username)
    /* This part is where I have problem*/
    Option 1: 
    await db.save(resp_);
    Option 2:
    db.save(resp_);
    Option 3: 
    db.save(resp_).then(param => /*Do nothing*/ clg(param)).catch(err => clg(err))

    res.json(resp_)
  }
};
```

I don't want to block async flow in this controller if I use option 1 it is going to wait for db.save() function to finish and I think there is no way I can implement this behaviour with async/await. Which option is preferable way or are there any other way I can sen response to client without blocking flow.

[Edit]: Option 2 is kind a silly implementation but I just added to understand differences.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do those operations simultaneously then you can use `Promise.all()` which parallelise the functions.

like,

```
await Promise.all([db.save(resp_), Promise.resolve(1).then(()=>res.json(resp_))]);`
```

Or, If you don't care if the data gets saved or not then Option 2 is not that bad of a choice.

Comment: If I wrap this line with try/catch block will I be able to catch errors from array of functions

Comment: Yes, cause if the functions throws errors promise all will also throw an error. then you can catch via the try catch block. But promise.all does both or nothing. Means, if one function throws an error it will throw the error without waiting for the other function.